# Needing help understanding "Leave to enter for six months" on a UK passport stamp

Tags: uk, passport-stamps

If the "leave to enter for 6 months" was granted on July 1, 2018 and you only stayed 3 weeks and then after the 3-month entry block you decided to come back for another month that following December, would your exit date remain the same or would the 6 months get reset as it was a separate trip?

Comment: It will be reset.

Comment: @Rachel There is no ‘3 month entry block’ within the UK immigration rules. The criteria for multiple entries, whether visa-free or with a visa, is that the visitor will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits, or make the UK their main home. See v4.2 https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

Answer (score 5):

Every time they let you in, you will get a fresh 6-month period. Your previous visits are not counted in order to decide how long you can stay.

With the obvious caveat that if this was not a visa free entry and was granted on a visa, then it's either 6 months or the expiry date of the visa, whichever comes first.